# Meaning of numbers in files WHATSAPP VOICE NOTES?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, notes

- I want to know how I cand find an especific voice note from de file ''WhatsApp Voice Notes''?
- I thought that the numbers of the files means year,  months or something like that but I couldnt find it because I have thousands of voice notes
- If I want an especific voice note from 18 February 2015 how will be named?
- I have the file on my PC so I can't use my smartphone

  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

On your PC ( or mobile ) do a wildcard search for `PTT-20150218*.opus` to get a list of all voice notes of 
18 February 2015

Folder numbering is `YYYYWW` where `YYYY` is the year and `WW` is the week number of year - `201726` is the folder for voice notes created in the current week (at the time of writing )

**Long answer**

As per  [How to get specific whatsApp voice note from your mobile](http://www.amazingtips247.co.uk/2016/04/how-to-get-specific-whatsapp-voice-note.html?m=1) which says

> Whatsapp creates folders and names them as **week numbers** of the year. So folder number 201612 (in the example above) means that what ever voice notes I've sent or received  between 21st March 2016 to 27th March, should be saved in that folder

(Emphasis Supplied)

In this example, week 12 of that year covers 21sr to 27th March

So, you would need to calculate from calendar the **week of year** your date falls in and see the corresponding folder, which happens to be `201508` (please double check the week number of year - I did it in a hurry )

---

**Edit:** I just created few voice notes and the logic given above is correct.

- Folder numbering is `YYYYWW` where `YYYY` is the year and `WW` is the week number of year - `201726` ( path `/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Voice Notes/201726` )
- Within the folder, files are arranged in `PTT-YYYYMMDD-WA000X.opus`, where `X`  increases as created

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp audio format is like this **AUD-YYYYMMDD-WAxxxx.opus/m4a/mp3/aac/amr** which are saved in the folder `WhatsApp/Media/Whatsapp Audio`.

WhatsApp voice format is like this **PTT-YYYYMMDD-WAxxxx.opus** which are in folder `WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Voice Notes`.
WhatsApp voice notes may have sub folders which created based on voice note receiving week number(Example: 201726(26-weeknumber)).

(Y-year, M-month, D-date, x-numbers )

Comment: yes. I am also confused about this. Because I got a voice note yesterday and the folder like this 201726(yesterday's date).

Comment: Isn't yesterday falling in 26th week of year? I think it is so the logic as per that source appears correct